# A good gateway for Facebook which doesn't require cookies?

Tags: facebook, cookies

What's a good gateway for Facebook? I've tried many, unsuccessfully.

I can't install any software or enable cookies on a PC with Internet Explorer. Also, *www.facebook.com* is blocked.

I've tried hidemyass.com and other similar websites, but when I login to Facebook I get an error message:

> You can't access because cookies are not enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You need cookies to access Facebook, otherwise many features will not work, so you are out of luck. The most you can do is use a proxy.